# Set new value to 2D array in C from method

Tags: c

So i have two 2Ds arrays and i need to change the value of the array1 for the value of array2 from a method.
How do i do this? I read about using pointers but i cant understand it.
If i print the array inside the method it works but no outside.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int change_array(char arr[10][10]);
int print_array(char arr[10][10]);

int main(){   
    char array1[10][10] = {
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '}};

    change_array(array1);

    //if i print here arr it prints empty and not like array2
    print_array(array1);
    return 0;
}

int change_array(char arr[10][10]){

    char array2[10][10] = {
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ','2','2','2',' ',' ',' ','3','3','3'},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {'4',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {'4',' ',' ',' ','6',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ','1',' ',' ','6',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ','1',' ',' ','6',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ','1',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ','5','5','5','5','5',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '}};

    //i want to change the value of the array1.
    arr = array2;

    //if i print arr here its changed and the same as array2
    print_array(array2);
    return 0;
}



int print_array(char arr[10][10]){
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        printf(" %c", arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Consider using `memcpy()`. You can't copy an array with `=`. All you do it to overwrite the **pointer** you were passed (the array decays to a pointer).

Comment: Joaco, Try `memcpy(arr, array2, sizeof array2);`  Does that work for you?

Comment: nope, still printing an empy array. its weird because if i print arr inside the function it works but no outside of the method

Comment: Then you need to [edit] the question to include a [mcve] so that we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Using `memcpy()` — or `memmove()` — correctly should work.  You need to show how `array2` is initialized, the revised copying code (how many `&` did you include?), and the printing code.  Without that, we can only guess — which isn't likely to be a useful exercise.

Comment: sorry, i updated the post with all the code now

Comment: Did you try `memcpy`?  If you did and that didn't work, show that code.

Comment: it works, i must have done something wrong the last time, is there a way to do it with pointers?

Comment: If you have fixed array size, consider wrapping it in a struct: `struct array10x10 { char data[10][10]; };` because then you can copy the struct (note that in this case, unless you really want a copy in the parameters, you will want to pass pointer to struct as function parameter, const if you don't want to modify the original and non-const if you want to be able to modify it). Note that this is just a convenience, assigning this struct is basically same as using memcpy...

Comment: @Joaco When you pass an array to a function, you're actually just passing a pointer to the array. So you're already doing it with pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in C, you cannot pass an array by value to a function. When you declare a parameter to a function of an array type, you are really declaring a pointer to the first element of that array. It is considered good practice to also pass the length of the array since the function has no notion of the length of it. For instance, when you write something like so:

```
int
change_array(char array[10][10]);
```

And then call that function with the name of the array you wish to pass:

```
char array[10][10];
change_array(array);
```

It is equivalent to passing the address of the array's first element:

```
change_array(&array[0]);
```

...and, in fact, we can rewrite the declaration of such a method to reflect this:

```
int
change_array(char (*array)[10]);
```

Which tells the compiler that `change_array` expects a pointer to the first sub-array within the two-dimensional `char` array that you have declared. The parenthesis must be used due to the higher precedence of the array subscript operators (`[]`) in the declaration. Otherwise, the compiler would expect an array of pointers to `char`, which is probably not what you wanted.

We can rewrite the definition for your function appropriately like so:

```
void // Nothing significant is returned, so use `void` type
change_array(
 char (*array)[10],
 int length)
{
  // Definition for array2 here.
  (void)memcpy(
    array,      // Destination
    array2,     // Source
    length*10); // Length (in bytes)

  print_array(array);
}
```

You must use the `memcpy` function, or loop over every element and assign it within the function, because we have a pointer to the elements, not the elements themselves. Make sure you include `string.h` so that you can access this function.